# backup strategy

Tags: backup

We have got a project about restaurant service equipment. We are asked to provide online backup strategy for our restaurant's web page. Could you give us any references? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more information about the server you are using for the web pages and how much access you have to it e.g. what is it's operation system, do you have admin access to the server ...

Comment: To help you out you first need to define your goals more clearly: What is the structure of your site (flat HTML, database-backed, etc.)? What do you want to be able to restore? How fast do you want to be able to restore it? How far back in time do you want to be able to go? Are you looking for "redundancy", actual "backups", or both?  --- Answering lain's questions above will also be helpful in getting more specific / applicable answers...

Answer (score 0):

you can make automated backup for a remote server.
If you use any type of control panel (CPanel, plesk, ...etc) you will find an option to make backups using APIs.

If you don't, you can just rsync (or tar and ftp) the /home and /mysql/data folders to another remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse.html). It is an easy to set up program and it can be used for multiple situations.